# Как пересобрать индексы для первичных ключей IOT таблиц?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle 11.2.0.4. Есть индекс ориентированная таблица(IOT) размером в десятки гигабайт.

Выполняю `truncate table`. Запрос по `dba_segments` показывает наличие сегмента с первичным ключом таблицы  размером в гигабайты.

1. Пробую выполнить `alter index .. rebuild`. Получаю ошибку:

   > ORA-28650: Primary index on an IOT cannot be rebuild
2. Пробую выполнить `Alter table .. move tablespace ..`. Размер индекса в `dba_segments` не изменился.

Как проще всего пересобрать индексы или сделать что-то еще, чтобы они занимали меньше места?

Comment: если вы удаляете __все__ данные, то имеет смысл воспользоваться `TRUNCATE TABLE`, правда перед этим придется позаботиться о `foreign keys`...

Comment: Именно так я и удалял. Но индекс остался гигантского размера все равно

Comment: Я попытался воспроизвести проблему - у меня не получилось. Можно попробовать так: `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name DROP ALL STORAGE;` - может помочь если под MINEXTENTS было выделено много места...

Comment: @MaxU мы говорим об одном и том же? IOT и не убавляющийся индекс по первичному ключу?

Comment: да, создал большую IOT таблицу и сделал `truncate table` - размер индекса уменьшился почти в ноль...

Comment: хм, возможно у меня какие то специфические настройки БД. Пока не понимаю, в какую сторону смотреть

Comment: может баг... я тестировал на 11.2.0.4

Comment: @MaxU а как вы размер индекса смотрели? Я смотрел по `DBA_SEGMENTS`, возможно это не совсем правильно?

Comment: я тоже по `DBA_SEGMENTS` смотрел...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что дело в том, что IOT по сути и является индексом. По этой причине пересобрать этот индекс нельзя.

Чтобы высвободить место можно использовать команду `alter table ... shrink space`.

**UPD:**

В комментариях к вопросу @MaxU подсказывает, что у него на БД проблема не воспроизвелась и простое `truncate table` приводило к уменьшению размера индекса. Возможно дело в какой то специфичной настройке БД или еще чем то.